Can SwiftUI visionOS window width be dynamically set?
I tried with frame like for View:
@main
struct i2ElevatorApp: App {
    private var portraitSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 600)
    private var landscapeSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 400)
    private var landscapeSize2x : CGSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
    let sharedState = SharedState()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(sharedState)
        }.defaultSize(portraitSize)
        WindowGroup(id: "SubTransformationView", for: MyData.self) { data in
            if let data = data.wrappedValue {
                CardView(cardIndex: data.intValue, cardType: data.stringValue)
                    .environmentObject(sharedState)
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .defaultSize(portraitSize)
        .frame(width: CGFloat(400 * (sharedState.aaa.count + 1)))

But it does not work:

Value of type 'some Scene' has no member 'frame'


You can add .windowResizability(.contentSize) to indicate WindowGroup size with its content, the default value is .automatic.
WindowGroup(id: "SubTransformationView", for: MyData.self) { data in
   if let data = data.wrappedValue {
        CardView(cardIndex: data.intValue, cardType: data.stringValue)
            .environmentObject(sharedState)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(400 * (sharedState.aaa.count + 1))) //<- here
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
.defaultSize(portraitSize)
//.frame(width: CGFloat(400 * (sharedState.aaa.count + 1)))
.windowResizability(.contentSize) //<- here

